# Store and retrieve NSAttributed string with NSTextAttachment to/from Pasteboard

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, uipasteboard, nstextattachment

I have `NSAttributedString` with `NSTextAttachment`. I've created subclass of `NSTextAttachment` (with implemented encode/decode methods) and it has property `attachedView` so I can put any view as `NSAttachment` into attributed string. The problem that I cannot store and retrieve attachment to/from `UIPateboard`.

Any suggestions how it can be done?

```
//Store
NSData *data = [[self.storage attributedSubstringFromRange:self.selectedRange] archivedData];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setItems:@[[(id)kUTTypePlainText: attributedString.string],
                                             [(id)kUTTypeData: data]]];

//Retrieve
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] loadAttributedString];
if (!attributedString) {
    [super paste:sender];
    return;
}

//Extension
@implementation NSAttributedString (Additions)

- (NSData *)archivedData {
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)unarchiveWithData:(NSData *)data {
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}

@end
```

Comment: Copy/paste code please. Images can't be referenced.